# Кто как пользуется констрейнтами?

Tags: swift, objective-c, constraints, ios, layout

Какие именно способы вы используете?

VFL? Или из кода NSLayoutConstraint без стрингов? Или в storyboard? Или еще как-то?

Какие варианты когда удобней, и какие чаще?

Народ, поделитесь опытом :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изучил констрейны полностью вдоль и поперек, и мой вердикт таков.
NSLayoutConstraint как вызов методов, так и VFL не исключают друг друга, а дополняют. И есть правила, которые не вписываются ни туда, ни туда, это методы вьюх, такие как:

```
setContentCompressionResistancePriority:forAxis
setContentHuggingPriority:forAxis:
```

Стандартный способ построения кострейнов самый убогий, я хуже ни чего не видел. Задался этим вопросом и нашел самую крутую либу, которой пользуюсь по сей день. Это [Masonry](https://github.com/Masonry/Masonry) для objc, и [Snappy](https://github.com/Masonry/Snappy) для Swift. Лучше ничего не нашел. Скорость верстки максимальная. Скорость дебага верстки максимальная. Уже как год ничего лучше не придумали, хотя хорошие идеи есть, но пока не очень понятны их плюсы.

Comment: Спасибо за либы. Тоже сегодня начал искать и нашел их в том числе, теперь знаю, что выбрать)

Answer (score 1):

для начала лучше всего расставить все объекты отталкиваясь от центра, потом как всё расставили делайте одному объекту который был поставлен первым Add missing constraints , расставится всё автоматом на все объекты, запускаете, проверяете, если всё печально, тогда берете каждому объекту кроме первого делаете clean constraints затем сразу же add missing constraints и так по очереди каждому объекту, а в целом это очень универсальная вещь и ОЧЕНЬ много способов их использовать а так же контролировать в дальнейшем расположение объектов динамически, но именно к этому моменту придётся прийти самому, по честному